# In the C language, what does "return ~0" mean?

Tags: c, return-value

I'm dealing with some C code that includes

```
return ~0;
```

What does that mean? It's pretty much impossible to google for...

Comment: Google for "c operators" and you'll find it.

Comment: someone being clever. It is the same as -1.

Comment: In cases like these, you need to think of alternative queries, like "C operators" or "C tilde operator"

Comment: @Byron Whitlock: ... on a two's complement machine. It is negative zero (`-0`) on a one's complement machine, and it is `INT_MIN` on a signed magnitude machine.

Comment: It's funny how the word "clever" in programming mostly means "stupid". I would not regard a constant expression that means different things on different CPU architectures as "clever" at all.

Comment: @R.: I think such a qualification is a bit rude and not at its place on SO. Somebody may be ignorant in certain places, without being and `idiot`.

Comment: @R: After learning what it does and going through the code, its usage makes perfect sense. In its particular case it was limited to returning an unsigned int, and also is unsure of the arch. Returning ~0 is as close to returning -1 as the author could get

Comment: What's the purpose of doing this ? What effect does it have ? I've seen this code in Git source code too

Comment: osager: it ensures that each bit of the returned value is a 1, regardless of the arch/type. This can be important if you're doing things with bitmasks or are generally doing a lot of bit-level operations

Comment: _Additional weight towards the argument that “there are good use-cases for `~0`”:_ Line 67 of OS X's `usr/include/dispatch/once.h`: `if (DISPATCH_EXPECT(*predicate, ~0l) != ~0l) {`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

~ is a bitwise not/complement, aka it changes all 0's to 1's and vice-versa. ~0 is a value with all bits set to 1.

Answer (score 7):

The key to answering this class of question as you inspect the code is to recognize enough of the structure of the language to know what question to ask. For example, the `return` statement requires an expression, of a type compatible with the declared return type for the function itself.

Knowing that `~0` must be an expression, it is either a really funny way to write a number, or it is an operator you don't recognize applied to the constant zero. That latter hypothesis is easily checked, and googling for "C language operator" will quickly lead to [dozens of tables of operators](http://www.google.com/search?q=c+language+operator). Nearly [any one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) of which will tell you that the `~` operator is a bitwise-not unary operator which inverts each individual bit of its operand. In this specific case, that converts the signed integer `0` to the integer represented with all its bits set.

On the majority of platforms you will encounter, that integer has the value -1.

Answer (score 4):

The `~` (tilde) operator performs a bitwise complement on its single integer operand.

Complementing a number means to change all the `0` bits to `1` and all the `1`s to `0`s

Comment: `~` is the bitwise NOT, as @user446034 pointed out in his answer. The ones' complement is a representation scheme for numbers in binary format that uses this operator.

Answer (score 3):

Anyway, for search queries with special symbols like yours "return ~0;" you can use
http://symbolhound.com/

It is pretty useful for programmer.

Comment: Excellent! Google's inability to do any kind of punctuation has been fairly painful for me in the past. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two independent parts here: `return` and `~0`.

`return` is a return statement. Read about it in your favorite C book.

`~0` is an expression consisting of bitwise-complement operator `~` applied to integer constant `0`. All bits in a zero value of type `int` are inverted (become 1) and the resultant `int` value (with all bits set to 1) is what the `~0` expression evaluates to. On a two's complement machine a signed integral value with such bit pattern (`111...1`) would represent `-1`.

Comment: @osager: “On a two's complement machine a signed integral value”.  Some programmers in some situations would like to make sure their code works in use-cases beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

Not zero or True.

Comment: It might not be good coding practice by the person who wrote "return ~0", but this answer provides a reasonable insight 50/50 probability of relevancy.  It's good that you're trying to explain something and not just going for the limited, mechanical answer.  I'd just qualify if by saying "look at how the calling code uses the return value... if it's always treating it as a boolean, then the programmer must be using it as a notation convertible to truth".

Comment: A bogus notation for truth; C has separate bitwise and logical operators for a reason. `!0` could make sense, but `~0` is nonsense (and as others have said, implementation-defined, so it should never be used except in hardware-specific bit-twiddling code).

Comment: Of course, but that is only logical reason for doing this, why should someone return this for any other reason? True is in most cases defined as -1 or !0 when return value is int.

Comment: That's right, but `~0` differs in that it signifies more than just "not zero" (so does `-1`). I think the statement "Not zero or true" is less correct than alternative definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The tilde does a bitwise compliment of the number 0, which returns back a value with all bits set to 1, with whatever size of the return value (so you'd get 0xFF for a char, etc.)

Comment: This is C. If you apply `~x` where `x` has type `char`, you will get the same thing as `~(int)x` due to default promotions, **not** `0xff`.

Comment: @R.. This occurred to me also, and now I'm stuck with an upvote